# Maximizing utility subject to a wealth constraint

Tags: optimization, binomial

Let $\tilde{E}$ be the risk neutral expectation, and $X_t$ the wealth that time t and $R$ the return of a risk-free investment. Consider maximizing the function $EU(X_N)$ subject to $\tilde{E}\frac{X_n}{R^N}=X_0$.

The solution is discussed in Chapter 3 of Shreve volume 1, and question 3.8.i asks to show:

> Fix $y$, and show that the function of $x$ given by $f(x)=U(x)-yx$ is maximized by $y=I(x)$. ($I(x)=\left[U'(x)\right]^{-1}$)

I might be misunderstanding what it means by "fix y", but as it stands this seems false. E.g. say $U(x)=\ln x$; then $f'(x)=x^{-1}-x/x=x^{-1}-1\not=0$.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: y = I(x) = x...?

Comment: @BCLC: yes, $U(x)=\ln x\implies U'(x)=1/x \implies I(x)=x$.

Comment: Then f'(x) = 1/x - 2x?

Comment: @BCLC: Sorry, the inverse of $1/x$ is $1/x$, so my comment is wrong and the formula in the question is right.

Comment: The inverse of 1/x is x :P

Comment: BCLC: No, "inverse" in this sense means that $I\circ U'(x)=x$. See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+of+1%2Fx

Comment: Oh crap. The question still stands?

Comment: @BCLC: Yes, still stands

Comment: Let y not depend on x. f'(x) = (1/x)-y(1). Set f' = 0...what's the -1 doing beside U' then I wonder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a different edition plus solutions manual.

[image]